# Can you recognize this grape?

Tags: species-identification, botany

This gorgeous and sweet grape I collected in central Italy. I would like to know the name of this variety to get more information about it. I tried to compare with some pictures in Google but I am no grape/wine expert so it's really hard to figure it out for me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm Italian, and that's an example of what we called *uva da tavola* , so these grapes aren't used for wine production. I think is the *crimson* variety.

Comment: Not sure at all.

Comment: @Marzipanherz — Because a proper answer would specify the grape variety in a scientific manner. The answer just makes the point that this is a table grape (uva da tavola in Italian), not a wine grape (which are not generally particularly sweet) and that it is sold under the name "Crimson". He also provides no evidence for his assignation (photo). Crimson appears to be an example of [Vitis labrusca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_grape_varieties) but may be an interspecies hybrid. However I am not competent to say if this is indeed Crimson.